# App is incompatible with all devices after publishing to the Market

Tags: android, android-manifest

Seems the Market is not happy with my app and makes it incompatible even with the two devices that I used to develop on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mikemeyer.taplocation"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.1.2" >


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/taplocationicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".TapLocationActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="PrefSettings"
            android:label="Settings" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And Here is the aapt dump output. It doesn't appear to have any inconsistencies that would hold up the process:

```
package: name='com.mikemeyer.taplocation' versionCode='4' versionName='1.1.2'
sdkVersion:'5'
targetSdkVersion:'11'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_CONTACTS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.SEND_SMS'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.telephony'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.location'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.location.gps'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
application-label:'Tap Location'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/taplocationicon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/taplocationicon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/taplocationicon.png'
application: label='Tap Location' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/taplocationicon.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.mikemeyer.taplocation.TapLocationActivity'  label
='Tap Location' icon=''
main
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240'
```

Comment: What do you mean it makes it incompatible with the devices you used to develop on? Do you mean you published to the market and then tried downloading to those actual devices? If so, you may need to uninstall any prior debug builds already on your devices and then instal the app from the market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've published to the market and then tried downloading to the same devices you've been developing on, you need to uninstall any prior debug builds already on your devices and then instal the app from the market.