# This app is incompatible with all of your devices

Tags: android, google-play

I get the "This app is incompatible with all of your devices." error when I try to install the application I just published on the market. I googled but couldn't find a solution to the problem..

```
aapt dump badging ~/myapk.apk
```

(I changed the names of the workspace and the apk and the application. rest is as is..)

```
package: name='com.example.test' versionCode='6' versionName='0.1.0.5'
sdkVersion:'8'
uses-permission:'com.example.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
uses-permission:'com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_SMS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_CONTACTS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.SEND_SMS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_SMS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS'
application-label:'MyApp'
application-label-de:'MyApp'
application-label-fr:'MyApp'
application-label-tr:'MyApp'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application: label='MyApp' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.example.test.WebSMSActivity'  label='MyApp' icon=''
uses-feature:'android.hardware.telephony'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'de' 'fr' 'tr'
densities: '120' '160' '240'
```

Here is my manifest-File:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="com.example.test.WebSMSApplication"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.GDActionBarWebSMS" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="WebSMSActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="PrefsActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="InfoTabActivity" />
    <activity android:name="WebContentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="AboutActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.test.ManualPagedViewActivity" />

    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".C2DMReceiver" />
    <service android:name="com.example.test.SMSSyncService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.example.test" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Does someone see if I have an error somewhere? Otherwise. Is there a way to "debug" why my particular device isn't able to install it? (i mean it is the same device I developed the application on! but i uninstalled it before I tried to install it from market..)

Comment: I notice you have a `minSdkVersion="8"`... what version of Android are you running?

Comment: It may not work if the permission com.example.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE does not exist yet on the device. Just a guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App is incompatible with all devices after publishing to the Market](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549452/app-is-incompatible-with-all-devices-after-publishing-to-the-market)

Answer (score 0):

If your app is a paid app, you might find the answer here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646997/our-andoid-app-registered-on-play-store-says-this-app-is-incompatible-with-all/48249445#48249445
```