# Our Android app registered on Play store says: This app is incompatible with all of your devices.?

Tags: android, google-play

We have developed and uploaded our application to Play store.
While we try to install on any of the devices it says the same error:  "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."

Additional information:

Size: 3.0M
Requires Android version: 4.0  and up

Please let me know what may be the expected error?

Comment: Did you restrict anything in the developer console? Sometimes this happens when there is a glitch with the play store.

Comment: Your android version must be 4.0 ++ on your phone. then try to install using play store using your phones market.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was driving me crazy. I went through the official documentation here:

```
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#defined
```

It lists 3 areas that affects compatibility:

- Device features
- Platform version
- Screen configuration

but it was none of those.

In the end it turned out that since my app is not a free app, I cannot install it using my own account and this is generating the confusing error "This app is incompatible with all of your devices". 
If I log into Google Play using any other account all is fine.